# Difference between general formula for cosmological comoving distance compared to Carroll's one

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion, integration

I came across two different formulas for the transverse comoving distance in cosmology from GR based on Friedmann's solution in the FLRW metric for an expanding space homogenoeus and isotropic:

a) ..the first one directly derived from GR (as shown in the scientific lieterature)

$$ d=\frac{c}{H_0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{Ω_k}}\mathrm{sinn}\left[{\sqrt{Ω_k}}\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{Ω_r(1+z)^4+Ω_m(1+z)^3+Ω_k(1+z)^2+Ω_Λ}}\right]  $$

where the operator sinn varies depending if we have an open, close or flat Universe. Obviously, $Ω_r$, $Ω_m$, $Ω_k$, $Ω_Λ$ are the omega density parameters whose sum is 1.

b) ..the second one derived by Carroll in his "The Cosmological Constant" Annu. Rev. Astron. Astrophy.  1992 30 499-542 (Eq. 25 page 511) which is slightly different

$$ d=\frac{c}{H_0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{Ω_k}}\mathrm{sinn}\left[{\sqrt{Ω_k}}\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{(1+z)^2(1+Ω_mz)-z(2+z)Ω_Λ}}\right]  $$

Indeed, if I multiply all factors in the square root at the denominator in this second integral b), I do not obtain the correspective part of formula a). I infer that the conceptual meaning is different. b) is defined in Carroll's document as proper motion which should actually be the transverse comoving distance for definition. Did I miss any important conceptual and mathematical steps bewteen the two formulas? Do you know when we have to apply Carroll's formula b) instead of general formula a)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you neglect radiation (i.e., set $\Omega_r=0$) and use that $\Omega_k\equiv 1-\Omega_m-\Omega_\Lambda$, then the expressions are equivalent.

Comment: right! Thank you! I derived it based on your suggestion.